# Cypress not launching chrome browser after "npx cypress run --browser chrome" command

Tags: cypress

I want to run tests serially (one after another) for that I used command `npx cypress run --browser chrome` but it is running headless in terminal I see this

From what I see in Udmey videos while I was learning it executes all the tests or .js files one after another in chrome browser

I'm currently using `"cypress": "^9.5.1",`

[image: terminal 1]

I tried with full path as well

```
npx cypress run --browser C:\Program/Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I give me

[image: terminal 2]

I tried with full path as well

```
npx cypress open --browser chrome
```

It just open the `Cypress` window with test names to select.

Is there a way to run all the tests one after another automatically with chrome browser open.
Sorry for if use bad english grammar

Answer (score 2):

With `npx cypress open` you get a button to run all tests.

Make sure you have the Chrome browser selected (above the "Run 38 integration specs" button)

[image]

---

You should also understand that `npx cypress run --browser chrome` is also running all the test in chrome.

Headless means you don't see the browser, only messages in the terminal. But  Cypress tests always run in the browser.

Comment: Here I have to select the test individually, but using `npx cypress open --browser chrome`  it will run all the tests without even opening the above window. That command will even open the chrome browser by opening the above window and running all the tests one by one till the last test and I'm not talking about the headless case.

Comment: No, that's not true - you don't have to run tests individually, you get a button to run all tests. It says **"Run xx integration specs"**.

Comment: I agree with you on that, plz check this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhLsUY4nbuI&ab_channel=QABoxLet%27sTest" time 14:00

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then you want to see that GUI window of Cypress is correct? If yes just clear the cache of cypress and run `npx cypress run` it will open the GUI.